Splitting slide into items left and according graphs on the right
I want to have some itemize environment on the left side of the slide and some graphs fitting the current slide on the right side.  I tried the following code:
\documentclass[compress,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

  \begin{columns}
  % Left column for itemize
  \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item A
        \item B
        \item C
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}

    % Right column for images
    \begin{column}{0.7\textwidth}
      \only<1>{%
        \includegraphics[height=0.6\textheight]{capital_A}
      }
      \only<2>{
         ~% Do not show capital_B
      }
      \only<3>{%
        \includegraphics[height=0.6\textheight]{capital_C}
      }
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}

\end{frame}

% Just testing
\begin{frame}
    \includegraphics[height=0.6\textheight]{example-image-a}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \includegraphics[height=0.6\textheight]{example-image-c}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Unfortunately this does not work.  For the first item graph3 is displayed and afterwards no graphs (and the items are moved downwards starting with item2).
How can I properly reach my goal?

Works mostly fine for me if I guess enough code to be able to compile the code fragment. Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

(probably unrelated, but height=\textheight is too height on a slide which also has a frametitle and you need to be more careful with your unprotected line endings, they add spaces)

You could either temporarily switch to another set of default overlay specifications or explicitly specify the overlays to ensure that both columns are uncovered starting from the first overlay:
\documentclass[compress,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]

  \begin{columns}[T]
  % Left column for itemize
  \begin{column}<1->{0.3\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> A
        \item<2-> B
        \item<3-> C
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}

    % Right column for images
    \begin{column}<1->{0.7\textwidth}
      \only<1>{%
        \includegraphics[height=0.6\textheight]{example-image-a}%
      }%
      \only<3>{%
        \includegraphics[height=0.6\textheight]{example-image-c}%
      }%
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}



Thank you.  This works.
Final question: The itemize environment is "jumping up and down" on the left side for pages 1, 2 and 3.  How can I sensibly fix this (for any size of image on the right side)

@AndreasTille Easiest way to avoid: use a top aligned frame
